# phonegap default helloworld example

Tags: android, cordova

I set up phonegap in windows 7 environement and insaled genymotion for emulating my virtual devices.

My problem or question is : Why i cant see any change in my app after i edit the default index.html in www folder.

This is the alterd code :

```
<div id="deviceready" class="blink">
                <p class="event listening">Connecting to Device</p>
                <a class="" href="#" onClick="alert('awsome !!!')">Device is Ready</a>
            </div>

            <a class="" href="#" onClick="alert('awsome !!!')">Awsome text</a>
```

Then i run the app in my emulator and i cant see any changes

Comment: are you using the phonegap client?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To "*compile*" changes in html, you must run compilation in cmd line once.
On android, compiling locally, the command is:

```
phonegap local build android
```

The command needs to be executed on project directory !